# Eclipse failed to response under Fedora 12

Tags: eclipse, fedora

i tried fedora12 yesterday, but i find eclipse doesn't work. at first i thought this problem is related to SELinux, but after i turn off selinux, i still can't 
create a project, i press the "next" or "finish" button, there is no response. well the "cancel" button works. there is no error popup, or error logs.

i tried eclipse -debug -console; but there is no log output when i click the button. it is so weird, is this happened to anyone before?

environment: fedora12, JDK 1.6.0_17, eclipse Galileo.
computer: t400.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug due to a change introduced in GTK 2.18, see [Bug 291257](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291257). The current workaround is to `export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true` before to run Eclipse. I actually use the following startup script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla/
export ECLIPSE_HOME=/opt/IBM/eclipse
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true 
$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't install plugins from update sites, either. 
In a blank eclipse install, adding a new  update site (es: jboss tools) using the keyboard works; also, it's possible to select a release to install from the available software list.
The new plugin gets installed, but won't appear in perspectives (es: jboss devel) after restart.
After that, adding new update sites and trying to install their releases won't work, the available software list remains empty.
Using Fedora 12 Eclipse 3.5..

By the way, "Fedora Eclipse" rpm is screwed at the moment, it won't install a single file

SOLUTION:
Eclipse 3.6 fix those problems http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ 
Just add helios update site

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an incompatability with gtk/gdk shipped with F12.  You can tell eclipse to use the native GDK and it should correct these problems:

GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 ./eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `-DGDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1` to your `eclipse.ini` file.  That should help if you switch workspaces.

Answer (score -1):

it's a bug, the keyboard works. try it.