# java error when launching newly installed Eclipse on Fedora 16

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora, x86-64

OS:  Fedora 16, 64 bit arch

I get the following error when trying to open the newly installed Eclipse Indigo:

Process /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/bin/java was killed by signal 6 (SIGABRT)

I installed Eclipse by downloading the tar.gz and extracting it into /opt

Then I created an executable in /usr/bin and also a launcher in
/user/share/applications

Eclipse splash opens where it lets me choose a workspace but then, when i pick
one and hit OK, it crashed

the err log file can be found [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=811754)

the problem remains even after upgrading to Java 7

thanks

Comment: Tried this yet? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1934508/139010

Comment: that did not work.  but thanks

Comment: I just had this problem as well. When I let it default to the "workspace" directory for workspace  as opposed to using an upper case "Workspace" the error went away. Fedora 17-very strange.

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to mention this was in KDE

i logged  into GNOME -- Eclipse opened no problem

when i went back into KDE, the bug was gone.  i can now use Eclipse :)

so the problem is solved.  i still would like to know what was wrong.